# Does it available reCAPTCHA for Swift3

Tags: swift3

I googled for the integration of Captcha in the iOS app but do not found any relevant way to do so. Even I sign up with reCAPTCHA and searched whether the plugins for Captcha are available for iOS or not? I didn't find any plugin for iOS there. Somewhere while RND I come to know that "it's not needed for the mobile apps", But the client wants the Captcha in his application so, I want to know:-

Whether we can integrate the Captcha in iOS App with Swift 3:-

If Yes? : Then what would be the relevant way to integrate it.

If No? : Then what is the relevant reason.

Comment: Captcha is a web pages things. It's a way of proving you are human, not a robot. Why would you need to prove to your iPhone that you are not a robot?

Comment: the client wants the Captcha in the mobile application, I can add in my android phone but can't get in iPhone

Comment: They aim to protect the system with automated submissions, which would consume storage space, introduce junk data and unnecessary administrative duty.Is there any ways to protect except Captcha